# Conditionally create dynamic types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have a base type of `BaseType`, and I want to conditionally extend this by merging multiple types when a discriminating value is set. If I were to discriminate to one type, I can create FooType and BarType and use a discriminating union value like `type` set to "foo" or "bar". But, I want to allow both FooType and BarType.

I potentially have many types, and allow it to discriminate any number of types.

Example:

```js
interface BaseType {
  base: string;
}

interface FooType {
   foo: boolean;
   fooType: string;
}

interface BarType {
   bar: boolean;
   barType: number;
}

interface BazType {
  baz: boolean;
  bazType: boolean;
}

// These are fine as long as it's only discriminating to one type.
myFunc({
   base: "",
   foo: true,
   fooType: "", // <== Should be an error if this is missing.
});

myFunc({
   base: "",
   bar: true,
   barType: 2, // <== Should be an error if this is missing.
});


// But I want to achieve discriminating several types this way.
myFunc({
   base: "",
   foo: true,
   fooType: "", // <== Should be an error if this is missing when foo is true.
   bar: true,
   barType: 2, // <== Should be an error if this is missing when bar is true.
});

// Another example
myFunc({
   base: "",
   bar: true,
   barType: "", // <== Should be an error if this is missing when foo is true.
   baz: true,
   bazType: false, // <== Should be an error if this is missing when bar is true.
});

// This can only discriminate to one type, but not both.
type AllType = FooType | BarType | BazType;
```

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPJD5N) what you're looking for? (Please check your code for typos, `barType` is `""` erroneously in there) If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?  (Note also, you are talking about `true` but you've shown no examples with `false`, so I'm presuming you don't care. If you *do* care, then we'll need to refactor to something else.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about the `barType`. I want `FooType` to be included when `foo` is true. If it's false, then I should not be able to add any properties from `FooType`. If `bar` is true, then I must supply all required properties from `BarType`, and so on. I hope this is clear. And yes, it's something I was looking for. No idea why it works though.

Comment: Okay but `false` isn’t the same as missing. Could you [edit] to show some test cases where you use `false` so it’s a [mre] and then I can suggest something appropriate?

Comment: (See previous comment) So, you'd need to refactor to something like [this version](https://tsplay.dev/m3q4Ew) where you pull out the `true`/`false` field to start with (how could the compiler look at, say, `BazType` and know which field is the discriminant one?). Does that meet your needs? If so, please do [edit] the question to explicitly include relevant use cases with `false` and not just missing, and then I'll write up an answer. If not, what remains?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unclear on some of the details of what you are looking for, but I think you can easily achieve what (I think) you are looking for if you use type unions and some boolean literals.

For instance, the following worked for me. In this example, I assume you want fooType to be required with foo true and barType required when bar true. I also assume you want foo data to be optional completely and bar data optional completely....

Anyway, does this give you something to run with?:

```js
// A helper type
type TrueFalseShapes<Optionals, BoolName extends string, T={}> = (T & {[Key in BoolName]: true} & Optionals) | (T & {[Key in BoolName]: false} & Partial<Optionals>);

// Example of usage:
type BarType = TrueFalseShapes<{barType: string}, "bar">;
type FooType = TrueFalseShapes<{fooType: string}, "foo", {base: string}>;
type BigType = FooType & BarType;
const a: BigType = {base: 'hi', bar: false, foo: false};
const b: BigType = {base: 'hi', bar: true, barType: "bar string", foo: false};
```

Edit: Cleaned up the suggestion to be a single utility type.

Comment: I have not tried this, and this would probably work, but I have more than 10 different types. Creating True and False version for each of then sounds very redundant. I'd prefer if I did not have to do that. Plus, Each `FooType` could have many properties, so repeating all of them for both True and False types is a lot of waste.

Comment: @CookieEater - I've cleaned up my suggestion a bit.  The helper utility should allow you to be pretty concise.

Comment: If you're unclear on the question, use the comments to ask clarification questions. That's what they are there for. The OP should then edit their question with the clarification. That helps everyone get a better question, and a better answer.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance @HereticMonkey.  I sometimes wonder what to do in situations (such as this one) where I felt that the question wouldnt be clear to me without writing a proposed solution.  I'm sure this is a common issue.  I should probably just read the guidelines and figure out a better way (instead of writing answers).